# Dockerizing node js passport authentication

Tags: node.js, docker, express, authentication, passport.js

I have made nodejs application with passport authentication in it. Its working fine sessions were also creating. My problem is that when I make docker image of this nodejs application session id is not creating. Is there any thing we have to do to create logged in session in docker. Please help